# How can I prevent VS2013 catching COM Exceptions with Dragon Naturally Speaking running

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2013, windows-10, naturallyspeaking

I have RSI, and when it flares up, I use `Dragon Naturally Speaking 12 Home` to save me a lot of typing. Generally I find it very accurate and my RSI subsides when I'm not typing so much.

However, I'm now using it on `Windows 10`, developing WinForms applications in `Visual Studio 2013`.  When running with the debugger attached, I'm getting a lot of COM Exceptions.

These occur in various places, mostly when when a `ToolStripMenu` is shown (when running nothing at all that accesses any COM component), and I have finally tracked it down to Dragon.

**If Dragon is running, even with the microphone switched off, the exceptions occur, but if I switch Dragon off, they do not**.

I used the same combination of software on `Windows 7` last year and had none of these problems.

Rebooting makes no difference; nor does also starting Visual Studio either before or after starting Dragon.

I want to avoid the expense of moving to a later version of Visual Studio or Dragon unless I know the problem is solved at the later version.

How can VS2013 be prevented from catching these exceptions?

---

**Edit to provide stack trace:**

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException crossed a native/managed boundary
  ErrorCode=-2147352573
  Message=Member not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020003 (DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND))
  Source=Accessibility
  StackTrace:
       at Accessibility.IAccessible.get_accKeyboardShortcut(Object varChild)
       at System.Windows.Forms.AccessibleObject.get_accKeyboardShortcutInternal(Object childID)
  InnerException:
```

---

The Stack trace is identical in all cases where the COM Exception is caught on show of a ToolStripMenu.

---

**Edited for conciseness and removal of irrelevant detail.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the helpful downvote.  I'm aware that it's not the greatest of programming questions.  However, it is a question about a programming environment, and I can't believe I'm the only person trying to run Visual Studio with a disability.  More than happy to close it or move it elsewhere if more appropriate.

Comment: Can you provide more details about the exceptions?

Comment: @MarkSowul example exception added to question.

Comment: Too bad "unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming" wasn't bolded

Comment: The callstack of the exception would also be helpful -- just trying to figure out why the exception might be happening now when it didn't previously -- maybe something about the app you're debugging this time around

Comment: Also I don't suppose Dragon's support is of any help?

Comment: There's also a debugger setting "break when exceptions cross appdomain or managed/native boundaries" -- is that on?  I think the default is off.  A lame workaround, but hey.

Comment: Sorry, possibly wasn't clear.  I only just recently installed Dragon on Windows 10 (RSI hadn't been bad for a while).  The exceptions started happening straight away.  It was on Windows 7 that I never had this problem.

Comment: Added the stack trace, such that it is!

Comment: Ahh I see, I missed that distinction originally - I was thrown by the VS 13 vs 15 -- I would guess that VS 2015 isn't going to help much, because it's much more likely to be a difference in interaction between the OS and Dragon.  Can you enable Debug -> Windows -> Modules and check if there's something related to Dragon hooked into the process you're debugging?  I'm guessing Dragon hooks in and its calls aren't being error-checked, so they bubble up to your debugging session.  Is there something in Dragon to exclude processes?  You can exclude your target if so and see if it helps...

Comment: @MarkSowul - you're exactly right!  There is indeed such an option in Dragon.  Would you like to offer this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Done and done [comment minimum length filler]

Comment: Yes it's annoying that questions about Dragon NaturallySpeaking often attract downvotes. I guess the average programmer prefers keyboard over speech recognition…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that VS 2015 isn't going to help much, because it's much more likely to be a difference in interaction between the new OS and Dragon.

Can you enable Debug -> Windows -> Modules and check if there's something related to Dragon hooked into the process you're debugging? I'm guessing Dragon hooks in and its calls aren't being error-checked, so they bubble up to your debugging session.

Is there something in Dragon to exclude processes? You can exclude your target if so and see if it helps.

Comment: Many thanks, this has really helped me. Constant pain when typing is not conducive to good programming.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so following Mark's suggestions, I found that by switching off the Debug option `break when exceptions cross appdomain or managed/native boundaries`, the exceptions were swallowed, but there was a noticeable irritating delay as the menus came up.

Then, as he suggested in the answer that I have accepted, I looked more closely in the Dragon options.  Since I had established that the main culprit was ToolStripMenus, the option to switch off voice commands for menus and buttons was an obvious candidate to try:

[image]

Unticking the option I've indicated in the screenshot made the whole problem go away.